# How to use ghost-cursor with playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I cannot use ghost-cursor with playwright

```
const page = await context.newPage()
const cursor = await createCursor(page)
await cursor.click(buttonSelector)
```

result:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'objectId')
```

Answer (score 2):

in parameter need send not selector but boundingBox.
like:

```
await cursor.click(await cursor.getElemBoundingBox(buttonSelector))
```

or:

```
await cursor.click(await buttonElement.boundingBox())
```